# Program only reading one line instead of entire file

Tags: java, token, filereader

```
    public static void main(String ar[]) throws FileNotFoundException{
    scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(new File("files.txt")));
    String nextLine = scan.nextLine();
    String[] fileNames = nextLine.split("\\s+");

    for(int i=0;i<fileNames.length;i++){
        System.out.println(fileNames[i]);
    }


    for(int i=0;i<nextLine.length();i++){
        char c = nextLine.charAt(i);
        boolean isWhiteSpace = isWhiteSpace(c);
        if(isWhiteSpace){
            if(c == ' ')
                System.out.println("white space (blank) at index "+i);
            if(c == '\n')
                System.out.println("white space (line feed) at index "+i);
            if(c == '\r')
                System.out.println("white space (\\r - carriage return) at index "+i);
            if(c == '\t')
                System.out.println("white space (\\t - tab) at index "+i);
        }
    }

}
```

I need help in solving this issue. Apparently my program only recognizes the first line in the file, when it supposed to be reading the whole file for the content.

What changes do I need to make for that? thanks.

Comment: Why do you think it should read the whole content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is because you are only reading one line from the file:

```
scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(new File("files.txt")));
String nextLine = scan.nextLine();
```

In order to read the entire file you have to call scan.nextLine() until you reach the end of file. To check for end of file you can do a while loop and thus go through the whole file:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("\""+filename+"\""));
while(input.hasNextLine())
{
    String data = input.nextLine();
    //Do what you want with one line which is at each iteration stored in data
}
```

Comment: I just tried it, but instead it just goes into a never ending While loop.

Comment: @user1769881 are you sure you typed it correctly? This should not result in an infinite loop...

Answer (score 0):

You only seemed to use `String nextLine = scan.nextLine();` once!

Answer (score 0):

String nextLine = scan.nextLine();

That seems to me to only be accepting one line from your file, using your Scanner "scan". Thus you are only getting one line from the file in question.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the method `nextLine()` only once, hence you are able to read only 1 line in your program. You have to add a for loop to keep on reading all line available.